# Fibonacci Numbers and the Harmonic Series

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers, conjectures

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}=H_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$$

Where $p_n,q_n$ are coprime intergers.

The first few values for $p_n+q_n$ are $2,5,7,37,197,69,504,1041,9649$.

When are $p_n+q_n$ Fibonacci numbers?

Due to the inequality, $\ln(n+1)<H_n<\ln(n)+1$, $\ln(n+1)q_n<p_n<(\ln(n)+1)q_n$.

Therefore, this would imply that $(\ln(n+1)+1)q_n<p_n+q_n<(\ln(n)+2)q_n$.

However, $\frac{\ln(n)+2}{\ln(n+1)+1}<\phi$ where $\phi$ is the golden ratio.

Though this is sloppy logic, because of this I thought it was likely are few cases where $p_n+q_n$ are Fibonacci numbers. The only solutions appeared to be $2,5$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Note that the following inequality holds:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}} \geq 1 + \sum_{i =1}^{\infty}{\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_{n+1}}}$$
where $f_0 = f_1 = 1$ and $f_{n+1} = f_n + f_{n-1}$.  This is from page 5 of this [document](http://www.elcamino.edu/faculty/gfry/191/HarmonicProofs2.pdf).

Comment: There is a high possibility that if a solution existed, I would not understand it. In light of this, should I delete this problem?

Comment: In my opinion, you should wait for a couple more days until such time that somebody gets to post an answer to your question.  Until then, you will know whether the proposed solution(s) are within your level of understanding / knowledge, or otherwise.